# Proxy into Webpack Dev Server

Tags: webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, storybook

I'm trying to put Storybook (https://storybook.js.org/) behind a Node Express app that proxies to the dev server. I'm using `http-proxy-middleware` to do the proxying.

Storybook uses `webpack-dev-server` when running in dev mode, and exports a static build for production.

Production works great:

```
  app.use('/', express.static(STORYBOOK_BUILD_FOLDER));
```

Here's my dev setup:

```
  app.use('/', proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:9001',
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      // 'Cache-Control': 'no-transform, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      // 'Expires': '-1',
      // 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    },
  }));
```

This loads Storybook initially on the Express server's port; however, subsequent attempts to hot reload the page fails with the followoing:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)
```

I'm not really sure how to debug this. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, I abandoned this line of inquiry.